# Going to the previous state after using fillAfter

Tags: android

In my application. when the user presses a button, the button dissappears (a layout animation is used) and another activity is launched. For keeping the button invisible I've used the fillAfter attribute. If the used presses the BACK key, the previous activity will be displayed with the invisible button. Is there a way to avoid this without re-building the layout in onResume?

Comment: Not clear on your situation, do you mean 'and then I start another activity and then when the back button is pressed to return to my first activity, the previously invisible button is now displayed'

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The steps are: 1. the button is pressed; 2. the button starts an animation and is made transparent and remains that way because the fillAfter attribute is used; 3. another activity is launched. 4. When pressing back, I want the pressed button to be visible again

Comment: Can you show the code of back button pressed and launching of another activity after animation.....then I can help. As I think there is some problem

Comment: There's nothing special with the code for launching another activity and I have no code for pressing the device's BACK key (the current activity is destroyed and the next activity on the stack pops up). The thing is that I'm starting an animation for a view. The animation has the fillAfter attribute set to true. This means that the last animation state will persist. So, if the animation makes the view transparent, the view will remain transparent after the animation finishes. I want to go back to the initial state (make the view visible in this case) after the animation finishes.

Answer (score 7):

You should call:

```
button.clearAnimation();
```

in your resume method. After that your button will be visible again!

Answer (score 0):

In your application, the activity in which animation occurs use the following code to start another activity :

> startActivity(new Intent(AnimatedActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class));
>
> finish();

After that in your Another activity when going back use the following code :

> startActivity(new Intent(AnotherActivity.this,AnimatedActivity.class));
>
> finish();

Comment: My answer helped you or not......if any confusion or anyother question then you can ask.

Comment: If you can't even communicate to get the answer then how could expect of getting the correct answer.

Comment: Restarting the entire Activity is not a solution to this puzzle. What if its a large complex Activity what cannot be simply restarted in its current state. Which is most of the time IMO

Comment: @Mitch Dart: Ya, actually that's right. It will not be a solution for large activity. So, you can do as it is suggested in above answer to stop /clear animation after animation got completed. So that you can retain the same state as before.